# Node.js + Investigate Request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node.js app. In this app, I'm POSTing some data via the [HTTPS module]. [1](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html). I would really like to be able to "see" what is being sent to the server via this request. Typically, I'd use Fiddler. But, in order to do that, I'd have to write a fair amount of addition code. Since Node is closer to the wire, it seems like there should be some way to just do something like `console.log` and print the request out to the console window. Is there a way to do that? Or, are there other recommendations in regards to how to monitor the output? Right now, my code looks like this:

```
let options = {
  host: 'example.com',
  port: 443,
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Token 12345'
  },
  path: '/api/endpoint',
  method: 'POST'                                
};

let request = https.request(options, (res) => {
  let body = [];
  res.on('data', (d) => {
    body.push(d);
  });

  res.on('end', () => {
    let result = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(body).toString());
    console.log(result);
  });
});

request.write(JSON.stringify(details));
request.end();

request.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `request-debug`? https://github.com/request/request-debug

Comment: @IzumiSy I'm not using the `request` module. I'm using the `https` module.

Comment: Then you can use `node-inspector` https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector